# C++ mosquitto client with TLS

Tags: c++, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I am creating a C++ MQTT client which use mosquitto Libraries and mosquittopp.h :

[Git Repository](https://github.com/hassinegabsi/mosquitto-c-.git)

I am trying to connect the client C++ to the broker but i got this error:

```
1646918108: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
1646918614: New connection from 13.38.126.191:60346 on port 9001.
1646918614: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1404A42E:SSL routines:ST_ACCEPT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

However, when i try to connect a NodeJs client with TLS i have succeeded :

```
1646918793: New connection from 13.38.126.191:60366 on port 9001.
1646918793: New client connected from 13.38.126.191:60366 as nodeJs (p2, c1, k60, u'client2').
```

So when i analyse the difference between the two clients, i recognize that is a problem with the protocol because in the Node client when i define the host of the broker like below :

```
var client = mqtt.connect("mqtts://mosquitto.ac-video.com:9001",options);
```

But in the c++ Client i did not know how to put the protocol with the host:

```
const char* host="mosquitto.ac-video.com";
```

Any suggestion please .

Comment: https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_tls_set

Comment: please don't post images of text